# FIrebase is effecting contact picker and displaying black screen

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am facing issue while implementing firebase in to the project. Just simple contact picker also stopped working after implementation. Clicking contact pick button displaying long lasting black screen and going no where. Only way is to close the app.

In sample issue is occurring second time. In my main project occurring every time.

Please find the source snippets below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package apps.uvr.com.apppoc;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1011);
                }
            });

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("EVent", state);
        AppController.mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("APP_EVENT", bundle);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Log.d("MainActivity","onActivityResult");
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="apps.uvr.com.apppoc.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Contact"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "apps.uvr.com.apppoc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.4'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Firebase has got nothing to do with this!

Comment: Without firebase it's working fine buddy

Comment: Post other classes code please

Comment: Posted everything in the sample i did. One Java, XML and gradle

Comment: Ok give me a moment

Comment: Works fine, I ran your code

Comment: @Veeresh Charantimath Can you check now. Updated MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. it seems that it is not related to firebase but play-services:9.x.x.

the below also looks like a same symptom.
[MultiDex api 19 cause freeze on Camera Intent onActivityResult not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651842/multidex-api-19-cause-freeze-on-camera-intent-onactivityresult-not-called)

Comment: Whats the solution?

Comment: in my case, the solution was only downgrade of play-services from 9.x to 8.x. I still trying to find a solution to use firebase since it is working only in 9.x.